# Install as root? how to install ".sh" files?

Tags: software-installation

what does this mean?

[image: ".sh" file screenshot]

```
rinka@ThinkCentre-M91-RINKA:~/Downloads/xdm-setup-7.2.11$ '/home/rinka/Downloads/xdm-setup-7.2.11/install.sh' 
Only root can do this
rinka@ThinkCentre-M91-RINKA:~/Downloads/xdm-setup-7.2.11$ sudo apt-get updates
[sudo] password for rinka: 
E: Invalid operation updates
rinka@ThinkCentre-M91-RINKA:~/Downloads/xdm-setup-7.2.11$ '/home/rinka/Downloads/xdm-setup-7.2.11/install.sh' 
Only root can do this
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: nevermind I found the answer here: https://www.itsfoss.com/xtreme-download-manager-install/

Answer (score 0):

here is the [answer](https://www.itsfoss.com/xtreme-download-manager-install/)
need to type:

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

Comment: Why do you need to run some script to install XDM? It's in the repositories, just do `sudo apt-get install xdm`

Comment: you're right lol, I haven't check it using: ```` sudo apt-get install xdm ````

Comment: No he needs to read the readme 1st ;)